# value from promise is not being exported to another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

https://jsfiddle.net/oc5v4bs5/
***<==link to the code***

when exporting `accToken` variable, it is showing undefined value. why is this showing?

```
//core modules
const OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2;

//vars
const clientId = '<myClientId>';
const clientSecret = '<myClientSecret>';
let accToken;
const oauth2 = new OAuth2(
  clientId,
  clientSecret,
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/',
  null,
  'api/token',
  null);
//make gotAuth promise
const gotAuth = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken('',{'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    (err, access_token, refresh_token,results)=>{
      if(access_token){
        resolve(access_token);
      }else if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
   });
});
gotAuth.then((val)=>{
  accToken = val;
});
module.exports = accToken;
```

Comment: you are exporting synchronously and assigning asynchronously. By the time the promise is resolved, the value has already been exported, and then it was undefined

Comment: Please post the code in your question.

Comment: Per the rules here, all code required to understand and answer the question MUST be pasted into the question itself and formatted properly to make it readable and cannot only be available via an external link.  This is because external links have a habit of changing or breaking over time and then the question is worthless as a long term reference which is an important aspect of stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting `accToken` BEFORE its value has been set.  `oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken()` is asynchronous.  That means it finishes and calls its callback sometime in the future after your module initialization has already finished and after your `module.exports = accToken;` statement executes.  So, `accToken` has not yet been set when your exports statement runs.

You will need to export the promise and let the caller use `.then()` on the promise to get the value.  Only when the promise resolves is the value available.  Or, you can export a method that returns a promise and let the caller call it upon demand and still use `.then()` on the returned promise to get access to the value.

```
module.exports = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken('',{'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    (err, access_token, refresh_token,results)=>{
      if(access_token){
        resolve(access_token);
      }else if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
   });
});
```

Then, where you use it:

```
require('./token.js').then(token => {
    // use token here
});
```